# I have a problem putting my camera in VirtualBox

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, webcam, camera

The problem is that I work with an Ubuntu system, and inside it I have also put two other Ubuntu machines to test if the cameras could be seen through the virtual Ubuntu machines. What happens that having installed the extension-pack of Virtual Box and then entering the menu to enable them even so the cameras do not work in Ubuntu.
Could someone tell me if I have to enter some command by terminal or something to specify that the camera is used in the virtualized Ubuntu instead of in the main Ubuntu? Thanks.

All system Ubuntu have the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

It still does not work, I attach photos so that you can see that the camera detects me in Ubuntu, but it does not work or does not show me the image.
[Camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT2Ec.png)
[Camera2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwC1y.png)
[Camera3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAaaK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the VirtualBox webcam passthrough feature..

To use this you will need to have virtualbox tools installed in your virtual guest instances.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/webcam-passthrough.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I need you to look at my posted because it does "detect" the Ubuntu virtual machine the camera but does not use it.